# How to recover a file that is been deleted from the mount device as root

Tags: linux, debian-wheezy

I accidentally delete a file from the mount device that too as a root. 
after deleting I couldn't even find a file in trash.

Can somebody help me to restore the deleted file.
I am using Debian 7

Comment: What file system do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If it's ext3/4 then try extundelete: http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/ For other filesystems there are other, similar tools.

I assume that you don't have any backups, right?

**AND STOP USING THIS DRIVE ASAP!**